# jQuery trigger link only once on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

I have a dropdown as follow

```
<select class="select-menu" style="display: inline-block;">
            <option value="1">Account Settings</option>
            <option value="2">Room Settings</option>
            <option value="3">Billing Information</option>
            <option value="4">Meeting History</option>
            <option value="5">Applications/Plug-ins</option>
</select>
```

This is my jQuery

```
$(".select-menu").change(function() {
        var bill = $('#billing-link');
        var room = $('#room-link');
        if($(this).val() == 2) {
            console.log(room.trigger('click'));
        } else if ($(this).val()==3) {
            console.log(bill.trigger('click'));
        }
    });
```

I want to trigger different links on different values (select).

Problem: These trigger works only once. If I re-select the option nothing happens

These are the links which I want to trigger on different select values

`echo  CHtml::ajaxLink ("Billing Information",
                   CController::createUrl('setting/billingInformation'), 
                   array(
                   'beforeSend'=>'function(){
                       updateHasTagInURL("Billing");
                       Loading.show();
                   }',
                   'complete'=>'function(){
                       Loading.hide();
                   }',
                   'update' => '#js_master_div'
                   ),
                    array('id' => 'billing-link')
          );`

`echo CHtml::ajaxLink ("Room Settings",
                   Controller::createUrl('setting/roomSetting'), 
                   array(
                   'beforeSend'=>'function(){
                       updateHasTagInURL("Room");
                       Loading.show();
                   }',
                   'complete'=>'function(){
                       Loading.hide();
                   }',
                   'update' => '#js_master_div'
                   ),
                   array('id' => 'room-link')
       );`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3hgKk/1/ - it works fine. you select first  time it trigger and reselect the same means it not trigger . select the other value and select that value it will be trigger this is dropdown nature

Comment: It trigger only once. No matter how many time you change the options from select.

Comment: I updated the code, but its not working now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3hgKk/4/

Comment: change the id in html part also  in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect. To check result follow link `[Click Here][1]` might be solve your problem

Comment: where the demo link??

Comment: It should work. For solution you have to share some more code so understand what is actual problem

Comment: Your updated jquery is working in case if we want to alert something using trigger. What I want is to trigger the link to make ajax calls and update the content using render partial.